# Who said that organizations tend over time to become more liberal?

Tags: united-states, liberalism, conservatism

I have often heard this quote: that organizations which start out as non-political, tend to move to the left, or become more liberal, unless they are explicitly conservative to begin with. I tried googling for the quote and of course got no hits for exact quotes and waaaay too many hits for words like "liberal".

I believe it was an American talking about American organizations.

Comment: Stephen Macedo, but I don't think we do trivia here.

Comment: The main advantage of StackExchange over search engines is you are asking real people for answers. Search engines cannot intuit, so this is the one site where I might get help. Research is research, I wanted to find the accurate quote and not go from memory. It's not trivia.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to require a comment for a down vote. I asked a legitimate question, it is directly related to politics. There are many helpful StackExchange sites, most are receptive to new members. This isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.opc.org/OS/html/V5/1a.html), it was John O'Sullivan, former editor of *National Review*. It's also corroborated on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_O%27Sullivan_%28columnist%29).

Comment: Hmm: Strange. One can frequently observe that individuals get more conservative as they become older (past student age, etc.)

Comment: Individuals, yes. But organizations move in the opposite direction. Probably because their founders die or move on to other things. It's kind of like a ship, take your hand off the rudder, it crashes on the rocks.